# HOW TO SEPARATELY VISIBLE A ROW CONTENT BASED ON VALUE-without VB

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office

I have some data from `2A` to `9D`.

I want a separate box and need to show all details of particular row based on the age I wish.

In the example I want to filter all data of a customer with age 15.(I know it is simple with filter option.But need to display content in another table (`A14:16D`)).

[image: My input & Output]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
{=INDEX($A$3:$D$10, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($E$11, $B$3:$B$10), ROW($A$3:$D$10)-MIN(ROW($A$3:$D$10))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1))}
```

**Note:**

- Enter this array formula in Cell `A13` finish 
  with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` & fill `right then 
  down`.
- Cell `E11` has age to filter records.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as 
  needed.